# Vim: vsplit and run external command

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map a command or function that splits a new window vertically,  switches the cursor to the new window, and runs an external command on the `<cWORD>`.

When I do:

```
:vsplit|wincmd w|execute '!perldoc <cWORD>'
```

Vim seems to run the the external command first in the current window and then when the command exits, Vim creates a new window and switches focus to it.

If I break these commands up into separate lines in a function and call the function, the same thing happens. Is there a way to have Vim do what I want it to do?

Comment: `:vsplit` already puts the cursor in the new window. Also, check out `:help K`.

Comment: `:vsplit` does not put the cursor in the new window automatically on my machine.

Comment: Then you should investigate why.

Comment: Why should I do that? It's not the problem here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My coworker Tye showed me how to do it:

`let w=expand("<cWORD>") | vnew | execute "read !perldoc " . w|1`

- Save `<cWORD>` as variable `w`
- `vnew` opens a new empty window
- execute `read !perldoc` passing `w` as the variable. The output is read into the new window
- Jump to the first line of the buffer in the new window

Comment: Your coworker showed you how to do something that's not what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't tell Vim otherwise, new vertical windows open on the left by default, leaving the cursor in the new window.

   [image: :vsplit]

   If that's not what you experience you should definitely investigate why.
2. After `:vsplit`, further commands are executed before the new window is rendered, in what you can imagine as a "virtual window".

   This means that, however unsettling it can be, you won't see the new window before the next command. That's how Vim works and there's nothing you can do about it.

   In the example below…

   - I have two perl files in the same directory,
   - in `perl.pl` there's a sample perl script I found online,
   - in `warnings.pl` there's a single word, `warnings`,
   - `perl.pl` is open in Vim with the cursor on `strict`,
   - I run `:vsplit|!perldoc <cWORD>`,
   - I expect to see the documentation on `strict` in my pager and the same buffer displayed in two vertical windows when I come back to Vim,
   - I close the left window,
   - I run `:vsplit warnings.pl|!perldoc <cWORD>`,
   - I expect to see the documentation on `warnings` in my pager and two different buffers displayed in two vertical windows when I come back to Vim.

   Let's see:

   [image: :vsplit2]

   Looks like everything worked as expected.
3. I don't see any but you probably have a good reason for opening that new window. I will suggest `:help K` and `:help 'keywordprg` anyway:

   ```
   set keywordprg=perldoc
   ```